# Issues inserting into arbitrary positions (not beginning or end) of doubly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

Ok to preface, this is to help with a school assignment. I understand there are unpythonic methods in the following code but this is the format they insist upon. In my insert method I have 4 cases to account for. All of them are dealt with appropriately except for else and im unsure why. For some reason the method insert isn't updating the linked list to include the new_node when this new_node is not placed at the end or start of the list. I'm unsure why this is as at the appropriate position we store the old value of current, we then store its previous and we set current = new_node, we then set new_node's next to be the old value of current and new_node's previous to be the old currents previous. I'm confused as to why this won't work.

```
class DLinkedListNode:
    # An instance of this class represents a node in Doubly-Linked List
    def __init__(self,initData,initNext,initPrevious):
        self.data = initData
        self.next = initNext
        self.previous = initPrevious

        if initNext != None:
            self.next.previous = self
        if initPrevious != None:
            self.previous.next = self

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def setData(self,newData):
        self.data = newData

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def getPrevious(self):
        return self.previous

    def setNext(self,newNext):
        self.next = newNext

    def setPrevious(self,newPrevious):
        self.previous = newPrevious


class DLinkedList:
    # An instance of this class represents the Doubly-Linked List
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head=None
        self.__tail=None
        self.__size=0        

    def search(self, item):
        current = self.__head
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found= True
            else:
                current = current.getNext()
        return found

    def index(self, item):
        current = self.__head
        found = False
        index = 0
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found= True
            else:
                current = current.getNext()
                index = index + 1
        if not found:
                index = -1
        return index        

    def add(self, item):
        new_node=DLinkedListNode(item,None,None)
        new_node.setNext(self.__head)
        self.__head=new_node
        current=self.__head
        new_node.setPrevious(None)
        current=current.getNext()
        self.__size+=1

    def remove(self, item):
        # remove the node containing the item from the list
        if self.__size == 0:
            raise Exception('List is Empty')
        current = self.__head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.getNext()
        if not found:
            raise Exception('Item not in list')
        else:
            if previous == None: # the item is in the first node of the list
                self.__head = current.getNext()
            else: # item is not in the first node
                previous.setNext(current.getNext())
            self.__size = self.__size -1


    def append(self, item):
        # adds an item at the end of the list
        new_node = DLinkedListNode(item,None,None)
        current = self.__head # Start the traversal
        if self.__size == 0: # check if list is empty
            self.add(item)
        else:
            while (current.getNext()!=None):
                current= current.getNext() # traversing the list
            new_node.setNext(None)
            new_node.setPrevious(current)
            current.setNext(new_node)
            self.__size = self.__size +1

    def insert(self, pos, item):
       # inserts the item at pos
        # pos should be a positive number (or zero) of type int
        assert type(pos)==int,'Error:pos is not an integer'
        assert pos>=0,'Error:pos must be positive'
        current=self.__head
        new_node= DLinkedListNode(item,None,None)    
        if pos==0:
            self.add(item)
        elif pos==self.__size:
            self.append(item)
        elif pos>self.__size:
            raise Exception('Position attempted to enter is larger than the size of linked list.')
        else:
            current_pos=0
            while(current.getNext()!=None):

                if (pos)==current_pos:

                    # storage is a holder variable
                    storage=current
                    right=current.getNext()
                    left=current.getPrevious()
                    current=new_node
                    new_node.setPrevious(left)
                    new_node.setNext(storage)

                    return True
                current=current.getNext()


                current_pos+=1
            self.__size+=1

    # doubly linked list
    #Hello(prev)<-->World(store data)-->None

    def pop1(self):
        current = self.__head
        previous = None
        while (current.getNext() != None):
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()
        if (previous == None): 
            self.__head = None
        else:
            previous.setNext(None) 
        self.__size -= 1
        return current.getData()

    def pop(self, pos=None):
        if pos!=None:
            assert pos<=self.__size,'Pos must be within list'
            assert type(pos)==int,'Pos must be an int'
            assert pos>=0,'Pos must not be negative'
        current=self.__head
        current_pos=0
        if pos==(self.getSize()-1) or pos==None:
            data_from_method=self.pop1()
            return data_from_method
        else:

            while current.getNext()!=None:
                if pos==current_pos:
                    data=current.getData()
                    left=current.getPrevious()
                    right=current.getNext()
                    left.setNext(right)
                    right.setPrevious(left)
                    return data
                current_pos+=1
                current=current.getNext()




    # doubly linked list
    #Hello(prev)<-->World(store data)-->None


    def searchLarger(self, item):
        current=self.__head
        current_pos=0
        while current.getNext()!=None:
            if item<current.getData():
                return current_pos
            current=current.getNext()
            current_pos+=1
        return -1


    def getSize(self):
         return self.__size

    def getItem(self, pos):
        assert type(pos)==int,'position must be type int'
        assert pos<=self.__size,'Position is outside of the list'
        current=self.__head
        current_pos=0
        if pos>=0:
            while current!=None:
                if current_pos==pos:
                    return current.getData()
                current_pos+=1
                current=current.getNext()
        else:
            current=self.__tail
            while current!=None:
                if current_pos==pos:
                    return current.getData()
                current_pos-=1
                current=current.getPrevious()

    def __str__(self):
        # returns a string representation of the list
        current = self.__head
        string = ''

        while current != None:
            if current.getNext()==None:
                string = string + str(current.getData())+''
            else:
                string=string+str(current.getData())+' '

            current = current.getNext()
        return string

def test():
    new_list=DLinkedList()
    for i in range(20):
        new_list.insert(i,i)
    new_list.insert(1,90)
    print(new_list)
test()
```

Comment: @StephenRauch When I attempt to insert a node into my linked list, if the node is not being inserted into the beginning or end of the list it doesn't get inserted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You currently have code that links the new node to nodes in the list, but no code that links the existing nodes to the new node. The only gesture you have in that direction is `current=new_node`, which doesn't achieve anything useful (since `current` is a local variable and you're about to return from the function).

You probably want something like `left.setNext(newnode)` and `right.setPrevious(newnode)`, though I'm not sure you've set up both of those variables correctly (one of them should probably be `current`, unless you're intending to replace an existing node).